# apache2 error Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf.d/: No such file or directory

Tags: apache2

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu 13.10 and apache2 is not working. When I try to start the apache2 server it is printing following errors:

```
 * Starting web server apache2
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 263 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf.d/: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Answer (score 13):

It was the same for me. After I created the `conf.d` folder still Apache 2 won't start. I was able to solve like this:

> Replacing this line
>
> ```
> LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
> ```
>
> with this one
>
> ```
> Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
> ```
>
> in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` solved the problem.

<sup>([source](/a/368542/212040))</sup>

Comment: Same problem, but not sure it was after the update or adding Xfce environment, also worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

When creating symbolic links make sure to use absolute paths

Instead of:

```
ln -s ./conf-available/mysite.conf ./conf-enabled/mysite.conf
```

You should use :

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/mysite.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mysite.conf
```

Comment: A relative path from the `available` directory does it as well (and is how Apache sets up the initial symlinks itself): `cd conf-enabled`, then `ln -s ../conf-avialable/mysite.conf mysite.conf`

Answer (score 5):

Perform a `mkdir -p /etc/apache2/conf.d/`. So the folder `conf.d` is created. Your `apache2.conf` file includes all files in this folder into the configuratin, and if this folder doesn't exist it run into an error. See:

```
user@host:~$ grep conf.d /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Include conf.d/
```

Answer (score 2):

For me there was and invalid shortcut inside the sites-enabled folder. Once I deleted that I could easily restart/reload apache.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full answer to the error :

> - Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
>
>   1. The apache2 configtest failed.
>        Output of config test was:
>        apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open c                                                                             onfiguration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
>        Action 'configtest' failed.
>        The Apache error log may have more information.

1. Run command `sudo mkdir conf.d`
2. Run command `sudo touch httpd.conf`
3. Run command `sudo vi apache2.conf`and replace

> LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

by

> Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

4. Save and restart apache

Many thanks to all for you very good advice

Best regards

Dunbo

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem with apache.
  **apache2: Syntax error on line 220 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open file configuration /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: No such file or directory**

Any consideration we are in the **/etc/apache2**
I solved this:
1- Knowing **sites-enabled/000-default.conf** is a link that points to **site-available/000-default.conf**, I went to check the content of sites-availables file;
And to my surprise, 000-default.conf is replaced by 000-default.conf ~ (because of gedit which always creates a backup)

2- Automatically I copy the file
    `$ sudo cp -v-default.conf 000 ~ 000-default.conf`

3- Restart `apache2`
    `$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

4- My server is started

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below [commands](http://gotechnies.com/setup-svn-server-ubuntu/)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/conf.d
```

Reinstall the packages.

Create symbolic links

```
ln -s /etc/websvn/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/websvn.conf
```

Enable the websvn configuration using below command.

```
sudo a2enconf websvn.conf
```

Enable the dav and dav_svn modules

```
sudo a2enmod dav
sudo a2enmod dav_svn
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into this today and had forgotten how I fixed it a few years ago.

In addition to replacing:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
```

with

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file, I also had to manually create the `httpd.conf` file in the `/etc/apache2/` directory.